# Call Same JS function in loop to perform for all requests simultaneously

Tags: javascript, php

I have one function of JS which I am trying to call from inside PHP code. I am calling this JS function number of times Loop is running ( 5 for example). 
Code:

```
    <script>
    //var seconds = '';
function csst(rowid){ alert(rowid);
    window.setInterval(function(){
        secondPassed();
        function secondPassed() {
        seconds = parseInt($("#ts").val());
        var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
        var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
        if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
            remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
        }
        $("#countdown1"+rowid).html(minutes + ":" +    remainingSeconds);
        if (seconds <= 0) {
            clearInterval();
            document.getElementById('countdown1'+rowid).innerHTML = "Buzz Buzz...";
              } else {    
            seconds--;
            $("#ts").val(seconds);
        }
        }
},1000);

}

</script>
<?php
$c = 1;
echo '<input type="hidden" value="50" id="ts" name="ts"/>';

echo "<table border='1'>";
while ($c <=5)
{
    echo '<script>
        csst('.$c.'); 
        </script>';
    echo '<tr><td>row'.$c.'</td><td><p id="countdown1'.$c.'"></td></tr>';
    $c++;
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

I need to have a simultaneous time decrement counter showing in each row of the table. using the same JS function.

any help, please !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow managed to solve this query. 
I just to play with the pickup variable in

```
echo '<input type="hidden" value="50" id="ts" name="ts"/>';
```

using this piece of code with dynamic-id creating in the loop and likewise dynamically picking the value in the JS function helped. Any other better approach is always good to have. 
updated working code:

```
    <script>
    //var seconds = '';
function csst(rowid){ //alert(rowid);
    window.setInterval(function(){
        secondPassed();
        function secondPassed() {
        seconds = parseInt($("#ts"+rowid).val()); 
        var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
        var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
        if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
            remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
        }
        $("#countdown1"+rowid).html(minutes + ":" +    remainingSeconds);
        if (seconds <= 0) {
            clearInterval();
            document.getElementById('countdown1'+rowid).innerHTML = "Buzz Buzz...";
              } else {    
            seconds--;
            $("#ts"+rowid).val(seconds);
        }
        }
},1000);

}

</script>
<?php
$c = 1;

echo "<table border='1'>";
while ($c <=5)
{
$val = $c+50;
echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$val.'" id="ts'.$c.'" name="ts"/>';
    echo '<script>
        csst('.$c.'); 
        </script>';
    echo '<tr><td>row'.$c.'</td><td><p id="countdown1'.$c.'"></td></tr>';
    $c++;
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Share any else solution as well please.